# Problem with my LaTeX code not compiling

Tags: spacing, equations, amsmath, compiling

i'm having problem compiling my LaTeX code. Recently i'm learning LaTeX to start writing my homework.The errors are: runaway argument?, Missing $ inserted.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[]{amsthm} 
\usepackage[]{amssymb} 
\usepackage{flexisym}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\title{Desarrollo}
\author{Example}
\date\today

\begin{document}
\maketitle 
\subsection*{Desarrollo}
\textit{
\textbf{iii.} Encuentre los intervalos de concavidad y los puntos de inflexión.
}



\text{Calculemos $f\textprime\textprime(x)$}

\begin{align*}
    &\text{Teniamos anteriormente que la derivada era}\\
    f\textprime(x)&=\tan x \cdot \sec^{2}x\\\\
    f\textprime\textprime(x)&=\sec^{2}(x) + [(1)\cdot(\sec ^{2}x)\cdot + x\cdot(\sec ^2x)\textprime]\\
    &=\sec^{2}x+(\sec^{2}x+2\sec ^{2}x \cdot \tan x)\\
    &=\sec^{2}x+\sec^{2}x+2\sec ^{2}x \cdot \tan x\\
    &=2\sec^{2}x+2\cdot \sec^{2}x\cdot \tan x\\\\
    &\text{Podemos factorizar por $\sec^{2}x$}\\
    f \textprime \textprime(x)&=\sec ^{2}x (2+2 \tan x)\\\\
    &\text{Entonces calculamos sus puntos criticos}\\


\end{align*}


\clearpage



\end{document}
```

Bonus: if anyone has a good resource to start writing my homework in LaTeX, i would receive it gladly.

Comment: Welcome! One thing you should do is to remove the empty lines before `\end{align*}`.

Comment: Thanks! there it is. Another question i have is: in the \text{Calculemos $f\textprime\textprime(x)$} it says bad mathchar. Any idea how to fix this? @Schrödinger'scat

Comment: Try `$f''(x)$` instead of `$f\textprime\textprime(x)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would get rid of the extra blank lines in the `align*` environment, and I'd rearrange parts of the material so that there's more visual focus on novel part, i.e., the derivation of the second derivative. For instance, I see no need to use a displayed equation to re-state the formula for the first derivative. Do use `\intertext` to typeset asides and explanatory comments. I would also replace all instances `\textprime` with `'`. (I gather you loaded the `flexisym` package to access the `\textprime` macro, right?)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % that's the default nowadays
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{amsthm,amssymb,amsmath}
%\usepackage{flexisym} % no longer needed

\begin{document}
\subsection*{Desarrollo}

\textit{\textbf{iii.} Encuentre los intervalos de concavidad y los puntos de inflexión.}

\medskip
Calculemos $f''(x)$.

Teniamos anteriormente que la derivada era $f'(x)=\tan x \sec^2 x$.
\begin{align*}
    f''(x)&= \sec^2 (x) + [(1)(\sec ^2 x) + x(\sec^2 x)'\,]\\
          &= \sec^2 x+(\sec^2 x+2\sec^2 x \cdot \tan x)\\
          &= \sec^2 x+\sec^2 x+2\sec ^2 x \cdot \tan x\\
          &= 2\sec^2 x+2 \sec^2 x \tan x\\
\intertext{Podemos factorizar por $\sec^2 x$:}
    f''(x)&= 2\sec ^2 x (1+\tan x)\,.
\end{align*}
Entonces calculamos sus puntos criticos.

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 \documentclass{article}
 \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
 \textwidth=16cm
  \oddsidemargin=1cm
  \usepackage{blindtext}
  \title{Desarrolo}
  \date{\today}
  \author{Example}
  \begin{document}
  \maketitle

   \section{Introduction}
    \blindtext

    \subsection*{Desarrollo}
    \textit{
     \textbf{iii.} Encuentre los intervalos de concavidad y los puntos de  
     inflexión.
        }

    \vspace{1cm}

    \noindent
    \section*{Calculemos $f''(x)$}


        Teniamos anteriormente que la derivada era\medskip

    \hspace{2cm}{  f'(x)= $ tan\;x \cdot sec^{2}\left[x\right]$\medskip}

   \hspace{2cm}{\begin{tabular}{rl} 
     f'(x)  = & $sec^{2}(x) + \left[(1)\cdot(sec ^{2}x)\cdot + x\cdot(sec  
    ^2x)'\right]$  \\ 
    =& $sec^{2}{x}+(sec^{2}{x}+2sec ^{2}{x} \cdot tan {x})$\\
    =& $sec^{2}{x}+sec^{2}{x}+2 sec^{2}{x} \cdot tan {x}$\\
    = & $2 sec^{2}{x}+2\cdot sec^{2}{x}\cdot tan {x}$\\
    \end{tabular}\medskip }   

    Podemos factorizar por $\sec^{2}{x}$\\\medskip    

    {\hspace{2cm}{ f'(x) = =$ sec ^{2} x (2+2 tan x)$\medskip}

    Entonces calculamos sus puntos criticos\medskip

    \clearpage

    \end{document}
```

This is formulated with the simple latex statements. You can modify according to your requirements,